# Firebase notification priority settings not working in android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notifications to certain users via the postman. The notification successfully reaches the device. However, it won't show in lock screens as well as a pop up from the top of the screen when the user is actively using the device (like WhatsApp notifications). How to send the notification with more priority to Firebase using the REST API?

```
{
       "notification":{
          "image":"",
          "sound":"default",
          "title":"Order Packing",
          "body":"We are packing your order"
       },
       "data":{
          "linkType":"order"
       },
       "default_sound":true,
       "to":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "tag":"orderStatus",
       "priority":"high",
       "notification_priority":"PRIORITY_MAX"
    }
```

Comment: Is the notification not coming or just not appearing when in foreground? If in foreground, you have to display a notification yourself using the plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm getting the notification while the app is in the foreground and background. But the notification priority seems to be very low. It won't show on the lock screen and the user will have to slide from the top to see the notifications.